# SVN commit after making changes in a file

Tags: svn

I checked out a project on a Linux machine. And made some changes on only 2 files out of many. I want to commit these 2 files back to the svn repository where I had checked them out from.

Say the svn repository link is :

```
svn://project_holder/project1/trunk/
```

and I made changes to project:

```
/trunk/script/file1.bash
```

Now in order to commit the changes, can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: You've not explained what you've done to try to solve this problem yourself. People will be much more willing to help if you can show some evidence of trying to solve problems yourself before you ask other people.

Answer (score 2):

cd to the working directory where you have made changes

and run the following command, substitute Description with an explanation of your changes

```
svn commit -m 'Description'
```

This commits the changes made to the files in that directory.

You can also explicitly specify the files, to commit changes only to those files

```
svn commit <file1> <file2> -m 'Description'
```